# Firebase Android: enabling users during registration

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase 9.4.0 to register and login users in my app.

I have a registration form, and I wish the administrator can enable or disable (via code, from his account inside the app) a user when asked to register.

In other words,  I would like that the registration of a user can be approved (via code, not using the Firebase console) by a administrator before become effective.

How can I get this?
I did not found sufficiently complete answer to this question.

Thanks!

Comment: i hope you will get your answer here http://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/ or else specify what actually you want

Comment: it seems to me that this does not resolve. I would like that the registration of a user can be approved (via code, not using the Firebase console) by a administrator before become effective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Firebase doesn't support user login approval by admins.

However, if this is a feature you'd love to have, consider this:

> Had Firebase supported user login approval by admins, the process
>   would look like this:

- User register using social login provider (google, facebook, etc) OR via email + password. In any case, you'll identify each user using a primary key (a feature unique to that particular user, like email id)
- Admin identify all users pending approval via the primary key and take further action (approve/ reject)

> Hence, a simple workaround for your problem becomes:

- Your app has one node in your firebase database which can be read/ write by public (no auth needed)
- Any new user who wants to login enters his primary key in registration form (say email id), which gets saved in your firebase database public node
- Admin would be subscribed to your firebase database public nodes and they get alert when new data arrives (ie, new user applies for registration request)
- Admin can take action (approve/ reject). This adds a property to the node containing user (in context).
- Users can check status of their registration request from the register/ login page itself. Just enter your primary key and check status.
- Once users see that their registration request is approved, they can proceed to login. If their request is rejected, they can take desired further action (like contacting admin via email)
- Once a user tries to register, your app fetches the primary key of the user, cross checks if the value is present in your firebase database public node and has approved status. If present and approved, your app logs in user gracefully.

Comment: @ValentinoS. You are welcome :) Thank you for the upvote. It motivates me to help more people

Comment: Any chance you can share with us how you resolved this.  I am trying to do the same with my app, but having a hard time figuring out how.

Comment: Hey @LizG this answer was posted on 2016. Firebase has since been bought by Google and has had gone through major changes. I would advise you to start a new question for relevant answers...